# Page not redirecting correctly

Tags: iis, redirect, https, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

So I'm trying to set up OWA, but I don't want my users to have to type in `https://exchange.foo.com/owa`

I've got the http redirect setup to redirect all requests to /owa so that narrows it down to `https://exchange.foo.com/`

I don't think my users are smart enough to type in that 's' at the end of http every time they want to access their mail.  I want it to redirect to the full url with the 'https' and all

I've read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998359.aspx)
which tells me that I should be able to use http redirect to redirect all traffic to `https://exchange.foo.com/owa` if I just type in the absolute path to the page. When I do that, I get an error saying that the page isn't redirecting properly.

So I do a URL rewrite. I download the [URL rewrite module for IIS](http://www.iis.net/download/URLRewrite) and follow the instructions listed [here](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/).  The page redirects perfectly! Then I'll sign into the forms-based authentication and the same error as before pops up - the page is not redirecting correctly.

Can someone give me a solution that works for them?

Comment: Your first method with the HTTP redirect is what you should have to do.  If you set that in IIS, you would just go to http://exchange.foo.com to get redirected.  You might also need to make sure Exchange is configured with the correct URL (https://exchange.foo.com/owa).  What version of Exchange, IIS, and Windows Server are you using for these?

Comment: Exchange 2010, IIS7 and Win Server 2008 R2. So you're telling me that setting the http redirect destination to `https://exchange.foo.com/owa` should work? Firefox still gives me an 'page not redirecting correctly' error when I tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this a little more complicated than it needs to be.

In the root of your Default Web Site just paste the following HTML code. When a user browses to `http(s)://exchange.foo.com` they will be redirected to the secure OWA page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Just a second...</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://exchange.foo.com/owa/" >
</head>
<body>
<h1>Just a second while you are redirected to foo.com's webmail...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, elegant solution. I also found out that somehow I had set up owa to redirect to itself so it was just redirecting in a loop. When I fixed that, everything worked (HTTP redirect, URL rewrite and your solution) to accomplish the same goal. Thanks :)